# OpenVPN with two gateway and DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn, gateway

i've got a network as describe in this schema and I would like to setup an openvpn to access it from outside.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Oqod.png

The name of my VPN server is relay.
Here is my openvpn configuration file :

```
proto udp
port 1194 
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert relay.crt
key relay.key 
dh dh2048.pem

server 10.2.0.0 255.255.255.0
;push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "route 192.33.160.0 255.255.255.128"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.33.160.64"

;client-to-client
;ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
chroot /etc/openvpn
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 1
```

My problem is that my servers use one DSL line with a sonicwall as a gateway (so all traffic from servers use the sonicwall as route by default) and my openvpn is one another DSL line from another ISP(=FAI). (and have another route by default).
So as you can see, when I'm connected on my VPN, I can't reach my servers because they don't use my vpn server as gateway.

Thanks in advance for anyhelp.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add a static route in Sonicwall to route 193.253.XXX.XXX (which I guess is your VPN network?) to 192.33.160.58. This should cause sonicwall to route traffic back over the network.

The other option is to use DHCP to push that route out to your clients (or statically define it there) but that may be more difficult/involved to do. It would be slightly more efficient since it avoids bouncing traffic through the sonicwall router.